# Show first 3 letters of email and hide rest of letters before @

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to make a function that shows the first 3 letters of an email and then hide the rest of the letters before the `@`.

My email could be: `TonyNielson@Stackoverflow.com` 
What i would like it to look like: `Ton********@stackoverflow.com`

This is my best attempt so far, but i cant seem to find out how make the rest.

```js
function hideemail(target) {
  var email = $(target).html();
  var hiddenEmail = "";
  for (i = 0; i < email.length; i++) {
    if (i > 2) {
      hiddenEmail += "*";
    } else {
      hiddenEmail += email[i];
    }
  }
  console.log(hiddenEmail)
}

hideemail(".email")
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="email">TonyNielson@stackoverflow.com</div>
```

Comment: Looks like javascript, not java.

Comment: You can use `str.indexOf("@")` to find the position of the char and stop putting joker character after this index?

Comment: I assume you know what you're doing, but I'm going to point something out anyway: This (and the solutions below) won't hide the email address from anyone scraping the site, or viewing the page source, because the modification is done in the front-end. If you wanted to actually obfuscate the email address, it would need to be done on the server-side.

Comment: In addition to what David has just pointed out, don't forget that the local part of an email can have less than 4 characters.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to check for the `@` symbol aswell.

Hence the condition becomes  `if (i > 2 && i< email.indexOf("@") ) {`

```js
function hideemail(target) {
  var email = $(target).html();
  var hiddenEmail = "";
  for (i = 0; i < email.length; i++) {
    if (i > 2 && i< email.indexOf("@") ) {
      hiddenEmail += "*";
    } else {
      hiddenEmail += email[i];
    }
  }
  console.log(hiddenEmail)
}

hideemail(".email")
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="email">TonyNielson@stackoverflow.com</div>
```

Comment: Or, `for (i = 0; i < email.indexOf("@"); i++){`